# SQL 2014 Equivalent of string_agg to return integer values

Tags: sql-server, for-xml-path

Unfortunately the `string_agg` function does not appear until SQL 2017, (I'm using 2014) so I've done a workaround using the `XML PATH`. It's working with one (fatal) flaw -- it omits the first `RoleID` every time - the first visible role is always preceded by a comma.

Background: I have a table with security roles stored as integer values, one security role (Called RoleID) per row. The sequence of columns is: UserRoleID, UserID, RoleID, etc (table shown below).I don't need the UserRoleID, just the UserID followed by a comma delimited list of RoleIDs.

For example, UserID 14 has the following roles: 1,2,5,6,7 and 8 in as separate rows in the UserRoles table. The XML Path that I've created (plagiarized - I'm not that good) returns the following -- you'll note that role 1 is missing, and the second role (2) is preceded by a comma. The results should be 1,2,5,6,7,8

RESULTS:

```
UserID  RoleID

14      ,2,5,6,7,8
```

Here's the SQL code:

```
SELECT UserID, RoleID = STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(UR2.RoleID as varchar(max) )
  FROM dbo.UserRoles AS UR2
   WHERE UR2.UserID = UR.UserID 
   ORDER BY RoleID
   FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
FROM dbo.UserRoles AS UR
WHERE UserID=14
GROUP BY UserID
```

Here's the raw table values for UserID 14:

```
UserRoleID  UserID  RoleID  ExpiryDate  IsTrialUsed EffectiveDate   CreatedByUserID CreatedOnDate   LastModifiedByUserID    LastModifiedOnDate  Status  IsOwner
37  14  1   NULL    1   NULL    1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.387 1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.387 1   0
38  14  2   NULL    1   NULL    1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.390 1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.390 1   0
39  14  5   2020-06-30 00:00:00.000 1   NULL    1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.400 1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.400 1   0
40  14  6   2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 1   2020-05-18 00:00:00.000 1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.403 1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.403 1   0
41  14  7   NULL    1   NULL    1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.410 1   2020-05-20 21:55:07.410 1   0
51  14  8   NULL    1   NULL    1   2020-06-12 16:14:25.640 1   2020-06-12 16:14:25.640 1   0
```

Any advice on how to get the first role to show up as expected for the selected UserID?

Comment: You're passing a 2 to the SUFF function so the leading ',1' is removed from the string. Pass a value of 1 instead to remove only the leading comma.

Comment: Dale K - that was it - Thank you! I'm not sure how to mark this as an answer but changing the value in this from 2 to 1 did the trick: OLD:  N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')  NEW: N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')  -- Thanks again!